# SMTP経由のメール送信を達成する為、ネットで紹介されたライブラリを使用したいが利用できない

Tags: php, mail

https://qiita.com/tsunet111/items/0ba0e8fc61882c3905c0
こちらの記事が比較的シンプルだった為、紹介されているqdmail.phpとqdsmtp.phpというライブラリを利用したいのですが、ページが表示されない状況で、困っています。
PHPのログをみると、やはり

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ATOZ\qdmail.php on line 661
```

と表示されていました。当方PHP Version 7.0.4です。

＝＝＝＝質問＝＝＝＝
現在起きている状況は、自分のPHPのVerに対応していないライブラリを選定している、ということでしょうか？それとも読み込みに失敗しているだけなのでしょうか？

Comment: マイナス票がついておりますが、"比較的初心者の私でも利用できるようなライブラリ、適用方法まで紹介された記事がございましたら　ご紹介を頂けますと幸いです。"の部分が主観的と感じられてしまう(人によって回答が変わる)のでマイナス票になっているのではないでしょうか？それ以外は問題ないように思われます。

Comment: @Myaku ご親切なご指摘をありがとうございます。不慣れでこういった面での指摘も非常に助かります。2番目の問い合わせは取りました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ①現在起きている状況は、自分のPHPのVerに対応していないライブラリを選定している、ということでしょうか？それとも読み込みに失敗しているだけなのでしょうか？

はい、PHP7に対応していないと思われます。（php5系統なら動くのでは）

> ②SMTPサーバを経由したメールを利用する上では、ライブラリを使うのが一般的のようですが、

無難なPHPのメーラーライブラリならPHPMailerですが、https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer　色々ありますので,自身で試して使い易い長くメンテナンスされているライブラリを選定してください。 
＊すでに作り始めているようなので、`mb_send_mail`等で処理を完成させてからどのライブラリを使用するか検討することをお薦めします。

追記、PHPMailerの送信サンプル（PHPMailer 6.0.2.　php7.1.6で送信確認しています。）
'Exception.php'、'PHPMailer.php'、'SMTP.php'のパスは実行環境に合わせて変更してください。
smtpサーバなどの設定もテスト環境に合わせて変更してください。
最後に、メールの誤送信に注意してください。

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    //$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Host = "smtp.hoge.jp";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->IsHTML(false);
    $mail->Username = 'a@hoge.com';
    $mail->Password = 'hogehoge';
    $mail->SetFrom('a@hoge.com');
    $mail->From     = 'a@hoge.com';
    $mail->Subject = 'test send';
    $mail->Body = 'test send';
    $mail->AddAddress('piyo@hoge.com');
    $mail->send();

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

追記、php `use` 名前空間について簡単な説明
phpは名前空間が指定されない限り、関数名が重複できません（`Fatal error`になります）、関数名が重複しないように名前空間を付けます（名前空間を定義するには、`namespace`　を使います。）
`use` はどこの名前空間なのかを指定しています、指定する名前空間はソースを見るか、ドキュメント通りそのまま指定します。（名前空間名\関数名;　ここに指定例あり-　https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading）

読み込むライブラリは、置いたパスを指定してください。以下（この送信サンプル）は、phpファイルと同じフォルダーに置いた例です。

```
//指定された名前空間の設定
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//ライブラリの指定は include include_once require require_once 何でも良いです
require 'Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';
```

Comment: いつもご支援をありがとうございます。これで今選択していたライブラリをきっぱりあきらめることが出来ます。貴重なご見解です。また的を絞って問い合わせさせて頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: なんと知らないうちに追記で貴重な情報が記載されていたとは。いつも本当１～１０まですみません。今から採用にトライしてみます、後ほど報告改めます

Comment: いつもご支援をありがとうございます、こちらの対応が遅れ申し訳ありません。
PHPMailer-masterをご提示のサイトから取得してまいりました。
あまりに当方初心者で未だライブラリの適用ができていない状況なのですが、
もし、当該Ｗｅｂページと同じフォルダに
Exception.php PHPMailer.php SMTP.phpの３種を、収めた場合は

useの部分は何か変更する必要があるのでしょうか？
それとも、requestの部分を変更する必要があるのでしょうか？
ひょっとして、ダウンロードしたPHPMailer-masterというフォルダごとどこかに配置すべきでしょうか？

配置から問い合わせてしまい申し訳ありません。

Comment: php use 名前空間について簡単な説明を追記しました。

Comment: いたれりつくせり、ありがとうございます。無事に出来ました